# How can I run docker for HyperLedger Playground installation?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm new to hyper ledger family and while I was installing the development environment from the documentation https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

I stuck at Step 4: Install Hyperledger Fabric:
By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04LTS terminal in windows(not bash, from windows store)
and the version of the composer it installed was 0.20.8
All the prerequisites are installed successfully.

It shows "`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`" I tried running docker with following commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
$ sudo service docker start
```

But doesn't help!!!

```
harsha@LAPTOP-UDDDOD20:~/fabric-dev-servers$ cd ~/fabric-dev-servers
harsha@LAPTOP-UDDDOD20:~/fabric-dev-servers$ export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv12
harsha@LAPTOP-UDDDOD20:~/fabric-dev-servers$ ./downloadFabric.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'downloadFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv12'
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

'''Tried Running Docker

```
harsha@LAPTOP-UDDDOD20:~/fabric-dev-servers$ sudo systemctl start docker
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
harsha@LAPTOP-UDDDOD20:~/fabric-dev-servers$ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                                       [ OK ]
harsha@LAPTOP-UDDDOD20:~/fabric-dev-servers$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is not running
harsha@LAPTOP-UDDDOD20:~/fabric-dev-servers$
```

How can I successfully run docker services and run hyperledger playground locally on my machine?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I would advise to move this question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site, it will be probably more likely to get some attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run docker easily inside of WSL (ie the version of ubuntu from the windows store you have installed).

The reason is that the windows subsystem for linux which you are using isn't a true version of linux with a linux kernel. It is a clever piece of software that translates linux apis to windows apis dynamically. Docker requires a true linux kernel in order to work.

I would suggest you use a hypervisor such as windows hyper-v, vmware or virtualbox and install a linux distribution into the vm and use that.

Comment: Okay! Thanks, Man
But is there any way to complete hyperLedger setup on windows without Linux?

Comment: Not for hyperledger composer.